# change time function from oracle to postgresql

Tags: datetime, postgresql-9.2

i have got problem with transfer 2 data function from oracle to postgresql can you help me:

Data:

INTERVALL = numeric(10,0)

START_DATE = timestamp without time zone

REPETITIONS = numeric(10,0)

This expression i copy from case state. I must write equivalent logical action in postgresql.

```sql
 case when (extract(DAY FROM (START_DATE + TRUNC(INTERVALL*(REPETITIONS-1) * 7)))
   - extract(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) >= 0 then 'OK'
```

and second:

```sql
case when (extract(DAY FROM add_months(START_DATE, TRUNC(INTERVALL*
  REPETITIONS-1) * 12))) - extract(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) <= 0 then 'ok'
```

Comment: Please, in order to avoid guessing games, describe your tables and provide better description of what you need to achieve.

Comment: i need only equivalent logical expression in postgresql

Comment: I think that for 1 this is good:
SELECT extract(DAY FROM (CURRENT_DATE + interval '1' day * TRUNC(7 *(2-1))))

Comment: I think comparing days is wrong and it is also wrong in Oracle. You would have better results if you explained your logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
case when (
    extract(DAY FROM (START_DATE + INTERVALL * (REPETITIONS - 1) * interval '1 week'))
    >=
    extract(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
then 'OK'

case when (
    extract(DAY FROM (START_DATE + INTERVALL * (REPETITIONS - 1) * interval '1 year')))
    <= extract(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
then 'ok'
```

Comment: Why you use * interval '1 week' ? not day ?

Comment: @ŁukaszWoźniczka, it would be much easier if you could explain logic of your calculations. For me `1 week` interval here looks natural.

Comment: @ŁukaszWoźniczka You are multiplying by 7 so I suppose you want weeks.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has way better support of [date, time and interval types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) compared to ORACLE.

I guess (sorry, but you haven't described this), that you need to compare `timestamp` column with the `current_timestamp` based on the interval, that is calculated from columns `INTERVALL` and `REPETITIONS`. I also think that in the first case you have something to do with week intervals, and months in the second snippet. (I don't fully understand the logic behind `TRUNC(…)` parts of your code.

I recommend the following:

1. rename `start_date`, removing `_date` suffix, as column's type is `timestamp` in fact, misleading;
2. convert `intervall` to `text` and store interval type directly, like `month` or `week`;
3. keep `repetitions` as is, defaulting to `1` for `NULL` values;
4. PostgreSQL supports `boolean` type natively, so you don't really need the `CASE … END` construct here, depends on the Application though.

Therefore the following query can do it (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3cbeb/5)):

```sql
SELECT start_dt, intervall, repetition,
       start_dt + (repetition||intervall)::interval
         >= current_timestamp AS is_it_ok
  FROM tab;
```

Comment: Its not my code :) I am only migration person :P Java developer not database admin ....